# time series aesthetics with ggplot2

Tags: r

hello I have tried to graph the following data
I have tried to graph the following time series

```
fecha importaciones
1   Ene\n1994         171.0
2   Feb\n1994         170.7
3   Mar\n1994         183.7
4   Abr\n1994         214.6
5   May\n1994         227.2
6   Jun\n1994         221.1
7   Jul\n1994         216.4
8   Ago\n1994         235.3
9   Sep\n1994         227.0
10  Oct\n1994         216.0
11  Nov\n1994         221.5
12  Dic\n1994         270.9
13  Ene\n1995         250.4
14  Feb\n1995         259.6
15  Mar\n1995         258.2
16  Abr\n1995         232.9
17  May\n1995         335.0
18  Jun\n1995         295.2
19  Jul\n1995         302.5
20  Ago\n1995         283.3
21  Sep\n1995         264.4
22  Oct\n1995         277.6
23  Nov\n1995         289.1
24  Dic\n1995         280.5
25  Ene\n1996         252.4
26  Feb\n1996         250.1
.
.
.
320 Ago\n2020         794.6
321 Sep\n2020         938.2
322 Oct\n2020         966.3
323 Nov\n2020         958.9
324 Dic\n2020        1059.2
325 Ene\n2021        1056.2
326 Feb\n2021         982.5
```

I graph it with office cal

[image]

but trying to plot it in R with ggplot

```
ggplot(datos, aes(x = fecha, y = importaciones)) +
    geom_line(size = 1) +
    scale_color_manual(values=c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"))+
    theme_minimal()
```

[image]

I have tried to graph with all the possible steps but it does not fit me in a correct way for someone to guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the x-axis to date class.

```
library(ggplot2)

df$fecha <- lubridate::dmy(paste0(1, df$fecha))

ggplot(datos, aes(x = fecha, y = importaciones, group = 1)) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"))+
  theme_minimal()
```

You can use `scale_x_date` to change the breaks and display format of dates on x-axis.